# UINavigationController always full screen not resizing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, ios9

I'm trying to make a modal popup appear when scanning QR codes.

I have a .xib file that has the necessary views and is linked to my custom view controller. The usual stuff, except that I have a navigation controller so that I can add a close button at the top later and/or in case I need to push another screen.

To make things a little more complicated, I do not have direct access to the view controller (code is in a manager file). This is the code to create and launch the popup:

```
self.m_scannerVC = [[BarcodeScannerVC alloc] initWithNibName:NSStringFromClass([BarcodeScannerVC class]) bundle:nil];

UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.m_scannerVC];

// Set the navigation controller to be a modal popup.
navigationController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;

// Set the size of the popup here.
navigationController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(100, 200);

UIWindow *win = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate window];
UINavigationController * winNav = (UINavigationController *)win.rootViewController;
winNav.providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle = YES;
winNav.definesPresentationContext = YES;
winNav.topViewController.providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle = YES;
winNav.topViewController.definesPresentationContext = YES;

winNav.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;
winNav.topViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;

// And now present the view in a modal fashion.
[winNav.topViewController presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:^{
    // Once presented, set the capture layer to fix inside our camera preview box.
    [self.captureLayer setFrame:self.m_scannerVC.m_viewCameraPreview.layer.bounds];
    // Adding the camera AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer to our view's layer.
    [self.m_scannerVC.m_viewCameraPreview.layer addSublayer:self.captureLayer];

    // Start the camera capture session as soon as the view appears completely.
    [self.captureSession startRunning];

}];
```

[image: This is what I am currently seeing - a fullscreen navigation bar with a root view controller]

Any tips on what I am doing wrong will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I found out why, I'm so stupid!

`navigationController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;`

should be

`navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;`